# Parse a SOAP request and modify data

Tags: java, netbeans, wsdl

I am developing an application to send a text message/sms to a user base and receive their responses. I have been given a *wsdl* which I have used to consume the service to sendsms using netbeans IDE .So far so good.
Now *the problem is* when I receive a text message a soap request is posted over to  a location on our server. The request-response is as  follows:

```
<a>http://www.csoft.co.uk/sms/api/sms_to_soap.htm</a>
```

I have checked the provider's sample API section but they do not have any material that does something similar.
My question is **how do I parse the soap request and send the corresponding response?** Also I have to check the messages and filter them for offensive/obscene content. I have the wsdl, xsd, java classes generated by netbeans, but I cant get around how to use them to achieve the goal. Any help or a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Kalyan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please search Stackoverflow and Google, there is plenty of howto around.
Even in this question, just check on the right at "related".